# Group parent nodes and get distinct of child nodes

Tags: xslt

I would like to write a transformation that should give distinct of parent node and distinct of it child node.

In the given example I am expecting distinct of Spocs and place collection.
But would you please provide a solution:

Input:

```
<DataCollection>
<Data>
<Item>Item1</Item>
<Price>6</Price>
<Area>Area1</Area>
<Contact>P1</Contact>
</Data>
<Data>
<Item>Item1</Item>
<Price>6.5</Price>
<Area>Area2</Area>
<Contact>P1</Contact>
</Data>
<Data>
<Item>Item1</Item>
<Price>6</Price>
<Area>Area1</Area>
<Contact>P2</Contact>
</Data>
<Data>
<Item>Item2</Item>
<Price>6</Price>
<Area>Area3</Area>
<Contact>P1</Contact>
</Data>
<Data>
<Item>Item2</Item>
<Price>6</Price>
<Area>Area1</Area>
<Contact>P2</Contact>
</Data>
<Data>
<Item>Item2</Item>
<Price>6</Price>
<Area>Area2</Area>
<Contact>P2</Contact>
</Data>
</DataCollection>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MainTable1>
<Record>
<ItemNumber>Item1</ItemNumber>
<Rate>6</Rate>
<PlaceCollcection>
<Place>Area1</Place>
<Place>Area2</Place>         
</PlaceCollcection>
<Spocs>        
<Spoc>P1</Spoc>
<Spoc>P2</Spoc>
</Spocs>
</Record>
<Record>
<ItemNumber>Item2</ItemNumber>
<Rate>6</Rate>
<PlaceCollcection>
<Place>Area3</Place>
<Place>Area1</Place>
<Place>Area2</Place>
</PlaceCollcection>
<Spocs>
<Spoc>P1</Spoc>         
<Spoc>P2</Spoc>
</Spocs>
</Record>
```

Xsl Which I a using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="ItemKey" match="Item" use="."/>  
<xsl:template match="/DataCollection">
<MainTable1>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Data/Item[generate-id() = 
generate-id(key('ItemKey',.)1])]"/>
</MainTable1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Item">
<xsl:variable name="currentGroup" select="."/>
<Record>
<ItemNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="../Item"/>
</ItemNumber>
<Rate>
<xsl:value-of select="../Price"/>
</Rate>
<PlaceCollcection>
<xsl:for-each select="key('ItemKey', $currentGroup)">
<Place>
<xsl:value-of select="../Area"/>
</Place>
</xsl:for-each>
</PlaceCollcection>
<Spocs>
<xsl:for-each select="key('ItemKey', $currentGroup)">
<Spoc>
<xsl:value-of select="../Contact"/>
</Spoc>
</xsl:for-each>
</Spocs>
</Record>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help to get distinct of Place collection and Spoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have realised you have to use Muenchian grouping here, which is good, but you actually need to do three lots of grouping in total.

First, you are looking for distinct **Item** elements. I would make a tweak to group the **Data** items by their **Item** value

```
<xsl:key name="ItemKey" match="Data" use="Item"/>
```

Then, it is just a small tweak to your current **xsl:apply-templates** to get the distinct 'items' you need

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Data[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ItemKey',Item)[1])]"/>
```

Now, within each distinct **Item** you are grouping separately on **Area** and **Contact**, so you need two separate keys here

```
<xsl:key name="AreaKey" match="Data" use="concat(Item, '|', Area)"/>
<xsl:key name="ContactKey" match="Data" use="concat(Item, '|', Contact)"/>
```

Note the use of the concatenations, as there you are grouping distinct elements within each distinct **Item**.

Then, to get distinct **Area** elements for a given **Item**, you would do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('ItemKey',Item)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('AreaKey', concat(Item, '|', Area))[1])]">
```

And similarly, to get the distinct **Contact** elements, you would do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('ItemKey',Item)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ContactKey', concat(Item, '|', Contact))[1])]">
```

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="ItemKey" match="Data" use="Item"/>
   <xsl:key name="AreaKey" match="Data" use="concat(Item, '|', Area)"/>
   <xsl:key name="ContactKey" match="Data" use="concat(Item, '|', Contact)"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/DataCollection">
      <MainTable1>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Data[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ItemKey',Item)[1])]"/>
      </MainTable1>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Data">
      <Record>
         <ItemNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="Item"/>
         </ItemNumber>
         <Rate>
            <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
         </Rate>
         <PlaceCollcection>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('ItemKey',Item)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('AreaKey', concat(Item, '|', Area))[1])]">
               <Place>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Area"/>
               </Place>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </PlaceCollcection>
         <Spocs>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('ItemKey',Item)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ContactKey', concat(Item, '|', Contact))[1])]">
               <Spoc>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Contact"/>
               </Spoc>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </Spocs>
      </Record>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<MainTable1>
   <Record>
      <ItemNumber>Item1</ItemNumber>
      <Rate>6</Rate>
      <PlaceCollcection>
         <Place>Area1</Place>
         <Place>Area2</Place>
      </PlaceCollcection>
      <Spocs>
         <Spoc>P1</Spoc>
         <Spoc>P2</Spoc>
      </Spocs>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <ItemNumber>Item2</ItemNumber>
      <Rate>6</Rate>
      <PlaceCollcection>
         <Place>Area3</Place>
         <Place>Area1</Place>
         <Place>Area2</Place>
      </PlaceCollcection>
      <Spocs>
         <Spoc>P1</Spoc>
         <Spoc>P2</Spoc>
      </Spocs>
   </Record>
</MainTable1>
```